# Error: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1

Tags: php, mysql

I get error while trying to run this code:

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$uname' AND password = '$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $num_row=mysql_num_rows($sql);
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

The issue is with the line `$num_row=mysql_num_rows($sql);`

The error message is:

```
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given
```

Comment: Without trying to sound rude, how come you bothered to ask a question without trying to google what's causing the error? There's at least 500 questions about the **very same** "problem" you had and that many answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$num_row=mysql_num_rows($sql);
```

should be

```
$num_row=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Count Rows after Query executes and get records.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$uname' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$num_row=mysql_num_rows($result);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$uname' AND password = '$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        $num_row=mysql_num_rows($result);

        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```